# ReactJS Performing Requests in the Component

Tags: reactjs

In React applications, where do you put the networking code. I have seen code as shown below. But in this case, the request is right there in the component and cannot be reused. I know I can use Redux but the products array is not meant to be shared globally with other components.

```
function App() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const getProducts = async () => {
       const response = await fetch(`someurl.com/products`)
       const products = await response.json()
       setProducts(products)
    }

    getProducts()

  }, [])

  const productItems = products.map(product => {
    return <li key = {product.id}>{product.title}</li>
  })

  return (
    <ul>
      {productItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: You may call the api somewhere in the parent component and pass the data in he child components as props.

Comment: So the basic idea is to always call the API from within the component. You don't move it to a separate file etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there is a lot of ways, of app architecture design for handling this scenario, depending of app scale.

The simpiest way to reuse and incapsulate such behaviour would be custom hook:

```
const getProducts = async () => {
       const response = await fetch(`someurl.com/products`)
       const products = await response.json()
       return products
}

export const useProducts = () =>
{
    const [products, setProducts] = useState([]) 
    useEffect(() => { 
        getProducts().then(setProducts)
      }, [])
    return products
}


function App() {
  const products = useProducts()
  const productItems = products.map(product => {
    return <li key = {product.id}>{product.title}</li>
  })

  return (
    <ul>
      {productItems}
    </ul>
  );
}
```